# Removing items from quote depending on custom condition

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, collection, quote, quoteitem

I am trying to use `sales_quote_item_collection_products_after_load` to remove items from a quote depending on a custom condition.

```
public function filterQuote(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
   /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection $collection */
   $collection = $observer->getProductCollection();
   /** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Quote $quote */
   $quote = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
   $items = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
   foreach ($collection as $product) {
     $customQty = $product->getCustomQty();
     foreach ($items as $item) {
       // We need to get the id of the simple product and not the parent.
       $simpleProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $item->getSku());
       $qty = (int) $item->getQty();

       // Check so the quote item matches the product and
       // compare the custom attribute.
       if ($simpleProduct->getId() == $product->getId() &&
           $qty >= $customQty) {
         // Remove the item from the collection.
         $collection->removeItemByKey($product->getId());
         break;
       }
     }
   }
}
```

I thought the above should work, but perhaps I should use some other approach. Right now all items still seems to be left in the cart even if I use `$collection->removeItemByKey($product->getId());` for all items.

Answer (score 0):

**you can try:**

Add below the code inside your condition for remove item from quote.

```
Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->removeItem($item->getId())->save();
```

Comment: But the event I'm using above is triggered after the quote loads its collection but as I understand it before it is rendered and saved - so the above should work?

Comment: you can try once @Cyclonecode